# In C# how can I create an array of arrays based on an array of objects?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of 4 objects. These objects are all of the same type and have many fields. I want to extract the fields Name, Code and Date from each object, put those values in a new array (one new array for each object) and then place these new arrays in an array. So I'd end up with an array like

```
[
   ["Bob","001","1/19/2021"],
   ["Tom","002","1/17/2021"],
   ["Dave","003","1/14/2021"],
   ["John","004","1/9/2021"]
]
```

Comment: Deserialize it into an `object[][]` (i.e., an array of arrays of objects) or a `List<List<object>>` (a list of lists of objects).  You might want to eventually transform that so that you use the inner array to populate class instances `public class Thing { public string Name {get; set;} public string Index {get; set;} public DateTime Date {get; set;}}`.  Since those fields are in a collection (without square brackets), you won't be able to do that directly.

Comment: This is really unclear, can you please show us the code of the objects ? it sounds almost that you have an OOP class containing your data and you try to serialize this data into an array of arrays ? and that snipped you posted is the desired Output - is that correct?

Comment: Rather than parallel arrays to store *related data*  you should learn about classes.

Answer (score 5):

Quite easy with LINQ:

```
//Assuming you have a variable "list" with your objects
var list = ........

var newList = list.Select(x => new[] { x.Name, x.Code, x.Date }).ToArray();
```

(shamefully not tested, pure notepad developing)

The first `Select` creates a new array for each object, containing the 3 elements from the 3 properties. The final `ToArray` call creates a new array containing the result of the `Select`, that is, each object turned into an array.