# Given list of classes, how to make list\array from specific property of class?

Tags: c#, list, concatenation

I have a class:

```
public class MyField
{
    private string fieldName;
    public string FieldName
    {
        get { return fieldName; }
        set { fieldName = value; }
    }

    private string fieldValue;
    public string FieldValue
    {
        get { return fieldValue; }
        set { fieldValue = value; }
    }

    private string fieldValidation;
    public string FieldValidation
    {
        get { return fieldValidation; }
        set { fieldValidation = value; }
    }

    private bool fieldValid;
    public bool FieldValid
    {
        get { return fieldValid; }
        set { fieldValid = value; }
    }
}
```

and then I have a list made of them:

```
private IList<MyField> myFields;

myFields = new List<SpectraNameField>()
{
    new SpectraNameField{FieldName = "FirstField", FieldValue="", FieldValid = false, FieldValidation="" },
    new SpectraNameField{FieldName = "SecondField", FieldValue="", FieldValid = false, FieldValidation="" }
};
```

I then populate `FieldValue` for each member of the list through my XAML, but let's say as an example I just say:

```
myFields[0].FieldValue = "Value0";
myFields[1].FieldValue = "Value1";
```

At the end I need to get all the values of `FieldValue` for each `MyField` joined using "_" (i.e. I need to get string "Value0_Value1")
How do I get list or array of all the `FieldValue` of my list of `MyField`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In C# how can I create an array of arrays based on an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800740/in-c-sharp-how-can-i-create-an-array-of-arrays-based-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: You can use LINQ as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800740/in-c-sharp-how-can-i-create-an-array-of-arrays-based-on-an-array-of-objects and then combine array members into a single string

Comment: Also, you should look into [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties) and [Automatic Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

Comment: @Felix yeah it kinda uses the same technique (LINQ, right?) as the answer below, being a complete noob to C# I need to read on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.Select`to get the values

```
 var fieldValues = myFields.Select(f => f.FieldValue);
```

Use `string.Join` to combine multiple strings

```
var joinedString = string.join("_", fieldValues);
```

Comment: Yep, that what I was looking for. What is the name for this syntax\technique so that I research it? (complete noob in C#)

Comment: @miguello `Select` is part of [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/)